# The USPTO is exploring crowd-sourcing options as a result of a recent Executive Actions

Tags: discussion

The White House announced new Executive Actions related to the patent system today. One of the actions is specifically about the mission of Ask Patents.

> "**Crowdsourcing Prior Art.** To determine whether an invention is
>   novel, examiners in the USPTO must find and apply information about
>   the state-of-the-art in the relevant technology. However, documents
>   reflecting this state of knowledge can sometimes be difficult to find
>   and incorporate into the patent-examination process. Today, the USPTO
>   is announcing that it is exploring a series of measures to make it
>   easier for the public to provide information about relevant prior art
>   in patent applications, including by refining its third-party
>   submission program, exploring other ways for the public to submit
>   prior art to the agency, and updating its guidance and training to
>   empower examiners to more effectively use crowd-sourced prior art.
>   This effort will focus on driving valuable contributions to the patent
>   process and to patent quality, strengthening a process that is vital
>   to innovation and economic growth. The USPTO will seek public input on
>   these efforts, as the Administration calls on the public and expert
>   stakeholders to partner with us to encourage the disclosure and
>   sharing of prior art, particularly hard-to-find references."

The other two are "**More Robust Technical Training and Expertise,** and "
**Patent Pro Bono and Pro Se Assistance.**"

http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2014/02/20/fact-sheet-executive-actions-answering-president-s-call-strengthen-our-p